# How to activate an conda environment when non-ascii characters are present in the zsh prompt?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, anaconda, zsh

Trying to activate any conda environment using IntelliJ's terminal results in this error:

```
    # >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 140, in main
        return activator_main()
      File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 1210, in main
        print(activator.execute(), end='')
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u279c' in position 41: ordinal 
    not in range(128)

`$ /opt/miniconda3/bin/conda shell.posix activate /Users/rschmidtner/github_repos/size_dashboard/size_dashboard_env`

  environment variables:
      AUTOJUMP_ERROR_PATH=/Users/rschmidtner/Library/autojump/errors.log
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
                CONDA_EXE=/opt/miniconda3/bin/conda
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/opt/miniconda3/bin/python
               CONDA_ROOT=/opt/miniconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=0
           CURL_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
                     PATH=/opt/miniconda3/bin:/Users/rschmidtner/.poetry/bin:/opt/miniconda3/con
                          dabin:/Users/rschmidtner/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin:/usr/local/sbin
                          :/opt/miniconda3/bin:/Users/rschmidtner/bin/shell_scripts:/usr/local/b
                          in:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/munki:/Users/rschmidtner/.
                          fzf/bin
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

     active environment : None
            shell level : 0
       user config file : /Users/rschmidtner/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/rschmidtner/.condarc
          conda version : 4.9.2
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.6.10.final.0
       virtual packages : __osx=10.16=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : /opt/miniconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /opt/miniconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/rschmidtner/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /opt/miniconda3/envs
                          /Users/rschmidtner/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.9.2 requests/2.25.1 CPython/3.6.10 Darwin/20.2.0 OSX/10.16
                UID:GID : 646382531:1566476737
             netrc file : /Users/rschmidtner/.netrc
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?
```

It seems that activate.py is reading the entire prompt and crashing out on the non-ascii characters. In my case that would be the arrow sign at the beginning of my prompt.
[image]

However, activating conda environments in iTerm instead of IntelliJ works. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding

```
export LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
```

to my .zshrc file solved the problem for me.